# Calculating path of a particle in a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods, vector-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

I have a file with .dat extension in which I have data for a vector field in form of columns arranged in order {position vector_x, position vector_y,x_magnitude,y_magnitude}. If I pick a specific position vector(x,y) and let's say drop a particle and I want to trace the trajectory of the particle for some time period. I have seen problems like having a vector field in some algebraic form and using Euler, Runge-Kutta method but with my problem, I am not sure what I should do any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It really depends... what does your vector field represent? Are they velocity vectors, force vectors, etc?

Comment: yeah sorry, I didn't mention they are velocity vectors. data is from PIV of a fluid flow

Comment: Is your problem that you don't have the value for the velocity vector field at all points but only at the few in the table? That you need to interpolate?

Comment: uhmm no, velocity vector field is defined for all the space with some finite difference between the measurements. For example, I have a vector field defined for the 0,1,2,3.. and so on but not for the 0.5 or any value between 0-1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some really easy iterations given a velocity field. The most basic iteration would be something like $$ \vec{X}_{k+1} = \vec{X}_{k} + \varepsilon \vec{V}_{k} $$ for small step sizes $\varepsilon$ where $\vec{X}$ is of course postition and $\vec{V}$ is of course velocity.

It would probably be a good idea to change the value of $\varepsilon$ at each iteration to adjust for when $\vec{V}_k$ gets very large. If the velocities in your fluid flow vary wildly, perhaps choosing something like $$\varepsilon_k = \frac{\alpha}{\|\vec{V}_k\|}$$

for some small constant $\alpha$ would be wise.

Methods like RK4 are always popular as well by treating

$$ \vec{V}_k = \vec{V}(\vec{X}_k) = \dfrac{\text{d}\vec{X}}{\text{d}t}(t,\vec{X}_k) \text{ .}$$

Comment: hey, I think get what you trying to say the method I was looking for is RK4 thanks. can you give me a link for the source where I can read more. I am very new to the implementation of numerical methods

Comment: I actually think the [wiki description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) is easy enough to follow for implementation. Many textbooks on numerical analysis go through the Runge-Kutta methods if you want to dig into the analysis.

Comment: hey I have 1 question. the examples of the RK4 I have seen have a function which they can use to calculate resultant quantity but in my case, as I don't know how the X changes with different values of position vector maybe I am missing something here

Comment: @chandsureja what do you mean by "resultant quantity"?

Comment: Like what should be my ODE for the RK4 method? the one that you wrote? if yes I am confused because its just the derivative of the position vector

Comment: @chandsureja That's exactly right. RK4 solves an ODE that looks like $$ X' = f(t,X) $$ and by definition, velocity is the derivative of position. You will supply a function $f(t,X)$ that takes in the position at $X=X_k$ and returns the velocity $V_k$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124106/discussion-between-chand-sureja-and-vb628).